# How to pull in the 'l' field from Active Directory into SharePoint user profile?

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, audience-targeting

I went into "Manage User Properties" within the User Profile Service Application.  I set the "Office Location" field and mapped it to 'l' within Active Directory.  'l' is used to contain our City (a.k.a. Location).  I then ran "Start Profile Synchronization".

**General Info:** (some of it...)
[image]

**Specific City Location** (I'm reusing "Office Location" field)

[image]

Then I clicked "Compile Audiences".  My end goal is to set up a different Target Audience for each city, but whenever I Compile Audiences, it's always empty.

I don't want to write back to AD, just pull one additional field into SharePoint.

Here's what the MIISClient shows (hiding the actual values):

[image]

Comment: Did you check in User profile, if it importing the City location? check your own profile and see if city location is updated.

Comment: City location does not appear in my profile. I'm sure the audiences would work after I can get it into my profile, but I don't know the correct steps to get it imported into the profile.

Comment: did you create new Property name City with Property Type of String( 100 Characters), and after that can you see the new property on Manage User Properties Page?

Comment: it is better if you add the screen shot, so clear alot of things.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I updated with a screenshot.  I didn't create a new property, I thought I'd try re-using the Office Location field since it wasn't currently being used.

Comment: that property is empty for your profile? did you check the MIISclient?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE  I checked the MIISclient and added a screenshot.  The field isn't listed as an attribute.

Comment: what i am thinking then, it is not properly mapped or Full Sync not completed sucesfully...did you run full sync or incremental sync. I would run full sync manaully

Comment: I think the Full Sync is what I was missing.  It's running now and I can see that field in the miisclient.

Comment: that's it then, once it compeleted then your stuff will work.I am adding it as anwser, if it solve the issue then please mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you map property, then you have to make sure following things.

1. properly mapped the property
2. then run full user profile sync followed by incremental sync( as recommended).

You can also check the MIISClient while Sync is running, if new property being imported or not.